# How do I click the clickable element in front?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I have two clickable elements, one in front of the other. Whenever I try to click the one in front, it thinks I click both. How do I make it so that it only clicks the one in front? HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML, CSS and JS.

Answer (score 3):

use event.stopPropagation

```
front.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  ...
});
```